What is the passive voice of sentence "When I met you."
The sentence when did I meet you? Is an interrogative sentence,
Its voice would be:
when were you met by me?
But the given sentence is When I met you.
This is not an interrogative sentence.
This sentence also starts with a conjunction as per the question.
Because there is not an auxiliary verb used.
This is also not a simple sentence.
Because it starts with a conjunction.
It is a declarative sentence.
Here when the conjunction is used to write an adjective clause.
--------when--------.
so we have clarified that it is a part of complex sentence.
There's a contradiction in its passive voice.
Because sometimes in some situations it should not be considered as a complete sentence.

Can you offer a reason for converting to passive?

Of course it's a sentence. It begins with a capital letter and ends with a terminal point.

'When I met you' is a subordinate clause, not a sentence.
'When I met you.' is fine as a standalone sentence fragment in response to a question, say. The passivisation 'When you were met by me' is possible, but clunky.
Note that 'meet' can be used (to mean a chance occurrence, a 'bumping into each other'), as a †'reciprocal verb' (ie a commutative verb, as with 'X married Y' =  'Y married X'), when passivisation is (in this example) unacceptable:

John met James quite by chance on Blackpool promenade.

=

James met John quite by chance on Blackpool promenade.

(=

J... and J... met quite by chance on Blackpool promenade.)

But

*James was met by John quite by chance on Blackpool promenade.

.............
The other sense involves prior arrangement:

John met James at the station as he had promised.

and passivisation is fine:

James was met by John at the station as John had promised.

†see Tal Siloni; Reciprocal Verbs and Symmetry

"When you were met by me." is the passivation of this sentence.
But it seems to be very uneven
Because this is a Clause
------------ sometimes considered as a sentence ----.
So if it can be considered as a sentence as follows
Because a clause expresses an action or a state of being, a clause can often-but not always-function as an independent sentence. A sentence can have just one clause or it can have multiple clauses. The only defining characteristic of a clause is that it must contain a related subject and verb.
Means it can be converted into passive voice
